# node.js async.series not working

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

This piece of code was taken straight out of the example from: https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback

```
var async = require("async");
async.series([
    function() { console.log("a"); },
    function() { console.log("b"); }
], function(err, results){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```

However it doesn’t work. It stops after printing "a".

Is it a bug with the latest build of async module or my usage have some issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The functions you provide in the array passed into async.series need to accept a callback parameter that the function calls when the task is complete.  So you'd want to do this instead:

```
async.series([
    function(callback){ 
        console.log("a"); 
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){ 
        console.log("b");
        callback();
    }
]...
```

Comment: it works. But i wonder why in their wiki they mention it this way
async.series([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
]);

Comment: where is `callback` initialized here?

Comment: This function appears to work even when I replace `callback` with `callbach`. Why does it work like this?

Comment: @AndersonGreen The `callback` parameter is provided by the `async` framework when it calls your methods.  It's saying to you: 'call this callback method when your function has completed its work'.

Comment: Whenever I invoke (one function using async.series) inside (another function using async.series), it calls the functions in the wrong order, as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554017/invoking-async-series-inside-async-series-produces-unpredictable-output

Comment: @JohnnyHK, can you have a look at an `async` related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646035/node-js-express-executing-mysql-queries-one-after-another-within-loops-in-a-s