# How does nesting async functions inside the final callback work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
var foo = function (callback_foo) {
    async.series([func1, func2, func3], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return callback_foo(err)
            }
            async.series([func4, func5], function(err){
                    if (err) {
                        return callback_foo(err)
                    }
                    return callback_foo(); //1
                });
            return callback_foo(); //2
        });
}
```

do I need to return callback_foo() two times? the first callback_foo() is to tell async.series func4, fun5 is done. And the second callback_foo() is to tell the outer async.series func1,func2, func3 are done. is that right?

Comment: See if this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12554540/290627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it like below.

```
 var foo = function (callback_foo) {
        async.series([
        func1(callback) {
            //func1 processing
            callback(); //this will call func2 after func1 is done
        },
        func2(callback) {
            //func2 processing
            callback(); //this will call func 3 after func 2 is done
        },
        func3(callback) {
            //do your func3 processing here,then call async.series for 4 and 5.
            async.series([
            func4(callback) {
                //do func 4 processing here
                callback(); //This will call func5 after func4 is done
            },
            func5(callback) {
                //do func5 processing here
                callback(); //this will call the final callback of the nested async.series()
            }], function (err) {
                //this is the final callback of the nested(2nd) async.series call
                callback(); //this is the iterator callback of func3,this will now call the final callback of the original async.series
            });
        }], function (err) {
            //final callback after all the functions are executed.
            return callback_foo();//call your foo's callback.
        });
    }
```

Note:callback used in func1,2,3,4,5 need not be defined,its async.series's iterator callback,thats helps us to move to the next function.
However i don't see the point of nested async.series calls.you could do it with 1 async.series call.

```
var foo = function (callback_foo) {
    async.series([func1, func2, func3,func4,func5], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return callback_foo(err)
        }
    });
};
```